# Slide in a hidden element on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a sliding menu from the right of the screen when the mouse is moved to the right side of the screen. When the element is not hidden we can give a `hover` effect or we make use of a `click` event. But i'd like to make slide in a `div` from the right when the mouse pointer is moved to the right side of the screen.

And I've got another query too.

I'm using `Twitter Bootstrap 3`.

Suppose I've got a `div` with a class of `test1` and inside of that div, I've got another `div` with a class of `test2`. If i make the `height` of the `test2`div to 100px; I guess automatically the height of the `test1` will be 100px. But in my case it's not happening. The height of the div `test1` remains 0px.

```
<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">
        ..content..
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `test2` a floating element? If so, a work around is to make `test1`  `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Post the CSS for test1 and test2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>Sidebar</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Main content</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar-wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    right: -180px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* for a bit of sexiness */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.sidebar-wrapper:hover {
    right: 0;
}
.sidebar {
    background: #acacac;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8rT9r/

Comment: Thank you monners. That really gave me a idea.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1: Track mouse position and write JS to show the menu in when mouse pointer is on right side of screen.

Way 2 : Have a 100% height and 5px(can vary as you want) wide div on right side of screen and show the menu on hover of that div.

Query 2 : If your outer div is floating please use clearfix to resolve height issue.

Comment: I'll give it a try of those 2 ways.